# creating a new mysql table with a primary auto incrementing id that is linked to another table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I want two tables to share a primary auto incrementing id, is this possible? how do i do this? is their anything i need to consider?

the reasons i am doing this, is because it is a better solution than adding groups column to the users table, and also better than creating a completly seperate groups table, because if they share a primary key, i can use the existing posts table for both groups and users. instead of having to create a two distinct posts tables, (group_posts table for group posts. and a user_posts table for user posts.)

**existing users table is**

id(primary, ai)

username

password

email

**my groups table that i want to link to my users table with a shared ai primary key**

id(primary, ai, linked to users table id)

group_name

created_by

creation_date

etc.

Comment: IF the two tables have the exact same primary key, there is no reason they shouldn't be a single table. Seems you're creating a 1-to-1 relationship between group & user, which appears odd.

Comment: by making them 1-to-1 i can reuse many of the pre-existing user functions and apply them to groups. so far example, following, posts, outputting posts, posting etc. groups and users are essentially the same. and i could differentiate the two by creating a column which identifies if the row is a group or a user.

Comment: the alternative to 1-1 would be making a group and users table completly seperate. this may pose an issue when outputting posts from my posts table. because the posted_to id would conflict with the users and groups table. i suppose i could create a column in posts that differentiates posted_to_groups, and posted_to_users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make you schema clearer by doing the following:

1. Create a table (e.g. `people`)

   - `id`, primary key, auto-increment
   - `type`, tells you if it's a `user` or a `group`
2. Make `users` and `groups` primary keys foreign keys on `people`

   - Insert records in `people`
   - Obtain the ID that was assigned using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`
   - Insert in `users` or `groups` appropriately, using the ID obtained above

Then you'd reference "people", and not "users" or "groups" in your `posts` table and so on.

Conceptually, thinking of it in an OO way, it means `users` and `groups` both extend `people`.